# Libraries load order on Tomcat 8+ from a single folder

Tags: docker, kubernetes, tomcat, filesystems, lib

Do anyone know what's the libraries load order based on, in a single folder on Tomcat 8?

Here is my situation:
There is this customer java application deployed on tomcat that, for some reasons, has a class in multiple libraries in the same webapp-shared folder. I know it's wrong, everyone knows that, but this customer refuses to fix this.
We have to deploy this application on kubernetes, so we created a Dockerfile and everything else, and it's working correctly *most of the time*.
When a pod is deployed on some nodes, it seems that the load order of the libraries is different, and that causes the application to not work properly.

So, basically, what I'm asking is: is there anyone who actually knows what's the load order based on? Is it the filesystem used? Is it the docker overlay? Can it be the LC_COLLATE? Is it actually pseudo random?
These nodes are basically identical and I'm really having a hard time trying to find out what the difference could be.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only ordering specified by the Servlet Specification is that classes in `/WEB-INF/classes` have precedence over `/WEB-INF/libs/*.jar`.

In Tomcat 7 and earlier the order of libraries in the `libs` depended on the underlying filesystem, so that it would break when you move your web application to a different OS or to a different Java EE server. In Tomcat 8 and later it is random by design. As random as a `HashSet` is.

See discussion in [Bug 57129](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57129). Regarding `Resources` and `PreResources` see [configuration reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/resources.html).